# TypeError: <sklearn.tree._tree.Tree object at 0x1a17272030> is not an estimator instance

Tags: python, graphviz

Can someone help me to understand why I am getting this error please :
TypeError:  is not an estimator instance.

Here is my code :

```py
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn import tree

model = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth = 3,criterion='entropy')
model.fit(x_train,y_train)

import pydotplus
feature_names = [key for key in df]
dot_data= tree.export_graphviz(model.tree_, out_file=None, feature_names=feature_names) 
graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data) 
graph.write_pdf("mines.pdf")
```

Comment: Show where you are getting the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should put your code in correct format.
For example:

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn import tree

model=tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=3,criterion='entropy')
model.fit(x_train,y_train)

#etc.
```

And when you export to graphviz use model (not model.tree_)

```
dot_LasDataOrig = tree.export_graphviz(model,  out_file=None, feature_names=feature_names)
```

Probably this line gives you the TypeError: is not an estimator instance.

Comment: Yes, it is this line that gives me the TypeError. Thank you, with model instead of model.tree_ it now works !

Comment: Wi Martin, if it works, mark the answer as right and selected, please.